# One of my mysql table's icon is changed and not showing data and when click to browse , download the page

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

MySql Table showing Browse: VIEW (0) on mouse over and download the page when i click for browse.

Comment: You'll have to give us more information. Which sql browser's icon are you talking about? What does a direct query using cli give you? Are you sure there is data in the table?

Comment: Are you talking about PHP Myadmin?

Comment: Yes pinaldesai I am talking about phpMyadmin.

Comment: abhinav I added a link of icon . Please see the link.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and upload the images to our image server.  If you cannot figure out how to do this, please [read this post on Meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a VIEW and no TABLE. VIEWS are something like queries combined in a table-like-thing which you can query and pull data from it with standard commands like `SELECT * from myView WHERE userID = 3`

Comment: Sn0opy thanks for answering. Have you seen the image. only tickeyallpass is creating problem another table with same icon are working means all queries are running on other tables.

Comment: I download the database and found there is no myd and myi file for changed icon table.

Comment: myi / myd file? Just make a dump of the database and show us the VIEW code.

Comment: I export and save the table query here. http://min.us/m1VZCFiP9 . please download. I choose complete export for this table but there is no insert query in file.

Comment: It's a bit hidden, but there's exactly what I meant: `VIEW ticketallpass AS select book_tickets.id...` please consider viewing the docs, for further informations how VIEWs work

Answer (score 0):

According to phpMyAdmin's source code, that icon appears if the table's comment is `VIEW`.

However I don't know what the significance of this is.

EDIT: Just seen Sn0opy's reply, that explains the significance. However that icon also shows up on tables with the comment "view", regardless of being a view or not.